# Using MAPIE for conformal predictions I get empty predictions sets when alpha is big

Tags: machine-learning

I'm using the [MAPIE](https://pypi.org/project/MAPIE/) Python library for conformal predictions. In the `MapieClassifier` I choose `method='score'`. When alpha is small (between 1% and 5%) I get non empty prediction sets. However when I look at a full range of alphas from 1% to 99% (e.g. `alphas = np.arange(0.01,1.00,0.01)`) the average number of classes in the prediction sets gradually go down to zero, despite the fact that in C. Molnar's book *Introduction To Conformal Prediction With Python (2023)* p.27 it is stated that « *A prediction set – for multi-class tasks – is a set of one or more classes.* », i.e. it's a non empty subset of the set of target modalities. I used a default XGBoost model on two classification datasets and got this phenomenon of empty prediction sets with big alphas, one of which was the [Dry Bean](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sansuthi/dry-bean-dataset) dataset mentioned in Molnar's book.

Here's a graph of the average cardinality of the prediction sets as a function of alpha.

[image: MAPIE 'score' method]

As we observe the average eventually go below one.

I also tried the code in Molnar's book at p.25-28 which doesn't explicitly use MAPIE but does a similar computation and got the same result that the prediction sets are eventually empty when alpha go bigger. I expected non empty prediction sets as mentioned at p.27 of Molnar's book. I observe that when alpha go bigger, q_level goes down which in return makes q_hat smaller. It seems like q_hat as a function of q_level goes down very quickly when q_level is between 0.7 and 0.9 (see the graph below).

[image: q_hat as a function of q_level]

**Questions :**

1. Is it something to be expected that the prediction sets get empty as alpha go bigger?
2. Should I change `method='score'` to another method to get non empty prediction sets?
3. Is there a *good practice* about MAPIE that I'm missing? Maybe one should avoid using big alphas, or using the method `score`, or something else. Intuitively, it seems to me that I should always get a non empty prediction set.

---

**2024-04-05 Update** :

So I dug a bit deeper in Molnar's book :

- p.50 : « To get the coverage down to 95%, MAPIE would have to start artificially generating empty prediction sets. It was a design decision of the MAPIE developers not to produce empty sets. Empty sets are difficult to interpret. »
- p.96 : « First of all, the prediction sets will get smaller. But what if the prediction sets had to get smaller than size 1 to achieve 1− coverage? Theoretically, the algorithm might have to produce empty sets to ensure exactly 1− coverage. In MAPIE, this doesn't happen, so it could be that the coverage is larger than 1− and doesn't change as you increase . A design choice. »
- p.96 : « But as  gets larger, more and more of the uncertain predictions switch to empty sets. »

So there is here a mention that predictions can indeed be empty but that MAPIE by design doesn't produce that, which is wrong because the default MAPIE method is 'lac' (i.e. 'score') which does produce empty sets when  gets bigger.

These empty sets were mentioned in the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00451) that defined the 'score' method :

- p.1 : « The optimal classifier can sometimes output the empty set, but we provide two solutions to fix this issue that are suitable for various practical needs. »
- p.3 : « A potentially undesirable property of the optimal classifiers is that they may lead to empty predictions, that is, H(x)=∅ for some points x∈X, especially when the required coverage is low. »

In the documentation of MAPIE too it is said that the method 'score' (i.e. 'lac') can produce empty sets. It seems like the best solution right now is simply to change to another method, which I tried and it does solve the issue of empty sets, as shown in these figures :

[image: MAPIE 'aps' method]

[image: MAPIE 'raps' method]

[image: MAPIE 'top_k' method]

**Conclusion :** The 'score' method does produce empty prediction sets when  gets bigger and I believe that the statements in Molnar's book about the fact that MAPIE by design does not generate empty sets is wrong.